# if inside mysql_fetch_array not working

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a strange problem in an IF inside a `mysql_fetch_array` that works weirdly ... working on the first occurrence and not on the next ones.

I have this:

```
while ($season != "2011/12"){
    while($res = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        echo "<strong>Resultado: </strong>" . $res['resultado'];    
        echo "<br />";  

        if($res['resultado'] == "V" || $res['resultado'] == 1){
            $total_titulos = $total_titulos + 1;
            echo "<strong>Total Titulos: " . $total_titulos . "</strong><br />";
        }       
    }
echo "<hr />";
}
```

`$res['resultado']` values can be: `V`, `F`, `SF`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, or `5`.

The variable `$total_titulos` is always incremented when it gets the value `1` but in case it gets a `V` it is only incremented in the first one it gets, and not on the ones after.

This never happened to me so I'm quite overwhelmed by this. Any help?

Comment: how about the echo? is that only also done the first time? from that code, it looks unlikely that the if is just "skipped". maybe there are spaces or other unprintable characters in the `resultado` column which let the comparison fail but which do not show up when echo'ed?

Comment: Yes ... the echo always shows up correctly! Never saw anythink like this! It's driving me nuts :) Also, I already checked the column resultado at the phpmyadmin and no apparent error there!

Comment: Are you sure `$total_titulos` is not reset somewhere else? Maybe the problem is in the code not shown here? Additionally, I guess your "real" code must look a little different anyway, since `$season` doesn't get modified anywhere, meaning that if its inequal to "2011/12", it would loop forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know what happened wrong, or what the problem was, but the problem was on the MySQL. This did the trick:

```
UPDATE resultados SET resultado="V" WHERE resultado="%V%"
```

Maybe some weird encoding.

Comment: Are you sure it was `=` not `LIKE`?